# How can you stop MySQL slave from replicating changes to the 'mysql' database?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have my slave set to not replicate the 'mysql' database as described in this `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;`

```
           Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
              Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
              Master_User: replication
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: master-bin.000001
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 1660
           Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000004
            Relay_Log_Pos: 478
    Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000001
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Replicate_Do_DB: 
      **Replicate_Ignore_DB: mysql**
       Replicate_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
               Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error: 
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1660
          Relay_Log_Space: 633
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File: 
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
```

Now, if I go to the **MASTER** server and issue a `GRANT` and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`:

```
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `foo`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I then go back to the **SLAVE** server and issue:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR `foo`@`localhost`;
```

and receive the response:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for foo@localhost                                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*E8D46CE25265E545D225A8A6F1BAF642FEBEE5CB' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I stop the slave from replicating changes the mysql database? I figured 'replicate_ignore_db' would have sufficed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, after a few more hours of investigation, I think I figured it out. Adding my answer in case this is of use to others.

According to the [docs on replicate-ignore-db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-ignore-db):

> **Statement-based replication.**  Tells the slave SQL thread not to replicate any statement where the default database (that is, the one selected by USE) is db_name.

Of course, statement-based replication is the default and what I was using. So I made the attempt to change the format by restarting the master with `binlog_format=row` to see what would happen. No dice. **GRANTS** and **REVOKES** still were replicated.

Further investigation into [the docs on replication changes on the mysql table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log-mysql-database.html) revealed

> Statements that change the mysql database indirectly are logged as statements regardless of the value of binlog_format. This pertains to statements such as GRANT, REVOKE, SET PASSWORD, RENAME USER, CREATE (all forms except CREATE TABLE ... SELECT), ALTER (all forms), and DROP (all forms).

Gah! Ok, so I checked the binlog using `mysqlbinlog` and my `GRANT` statement was not issueing a `USE mysql` database call (why should it?). So `replicate-ignore-db` could not in good conscience ignore the statement.

My solution was to cut the changes to the **mysql** table out of the binary log completely by adding `binlog-ignore-db=mysql` to **my.cnf** and restart the server. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Carefully study the algorithm if you have both `_do_` and `_ignore_` clauses.  It gets tricky.

Answer (score 5):

The issue with [Derek Downey's answer on this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/588/3690) is it will always work the same way (on or off).

If you are in a situation where you'd like most grants to be replicated but not this one - or you don't want to bounce mysql (necessary to load the modified my.conf file) you can do it this way:

```
SET session sql_log_bin = 0;

GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `foo`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';

SET session sql_log_bin = 1;
```

Please remember - that last line setting `sql_log_bin = 1` is very important because without it you will not replicate anything.