# Is there a slave configuration that stops replication of mysql.mysql and grants?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a mariadb slave that cannot have the same permissions and users as the the mysql master. Is there a way to configure the slave so that it does not replicate changes to the mysql system tables and does not try to run GRANT statements?

I am currently using `replicate_wild_do_table=mydb.%`, and I tried using `replicate_wild_ignore_table=mysql.%` but that did not seem to ignore the GRANT statements.

I noticed `replicate_wild_do_table=mydb.%` seems to be sufficient on a mysql slave to not replicate changes to the mysql system table, but it is not sufficient on a mariadb slave.

Answer (score 0):

Use binlog-ignore-db instead. This [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/588/70539) explains the behaviour and answers your question. If not, comment.